# AJAX Unexpected Token < JSON at position 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Everything looks correct with my Ajax call and action method but looks like it's returning HTML, instead of valid JSON. Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

```
Error: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "success!" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, ex.Message });
        }
    }

        $("#updateStatus").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("UpdateStatus","Home")",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: it looks like you're *sending* html to your server, which is unable to parse it, send us what you see on the server?

Comment: I tried your code and It working with me .. what is Exactly your issue ?

Comment: So what is being returned from the server when you look at the network request?

Answer (score 1):

I recently got the same error and changing `dataType: "html"` fixed the error. My controller method is returning a partial view so my case is a little different.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that every input has ValidationMessageFor Element

Answer (score -2):

you are missing the message tag in the catch block

Comment: Perhaps you could show how this could be fixed with an updated code snippet?

Comment: public ActionResult UpdateStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "success!" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }

Comment: Edit it into your answer, don't just put it as a comment. There's an 'edit' button below your answer.